# Calculate the Fiscal Quarter of a Date in a Formula Field if the FY starts in Aug

Tags: formula, formula-field, validation-rule, date

As the title suggests I'm trying to identify the fiscal quarter a CloseDate of an opportunity falls in, provided that the FY starts in Aug.

I have tried this as per document: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5 which states that one can provide an offset, but the formula is not returning expected values.

The formula I've used is:

```
CEILING( ( MONTH ( date ) - 7 ) / 3)
```

But this is not only not returning positive values, but returning wrong values.

The expectation is that Aug, Sep, Oct would be 1, Nov, Dec, Jan be 2, Feb, Mar, Apr be 3 and May, Jun, Jul be 4.

But the results are all over the place.

Can you please help me get a formula for calculating the fiscal quarter when the FY starts in Aug?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious problem with this approach is that January would evaluate like
`CEILING((1 - 7) / 3)` => `CEILING(-6/3)` => `-2`

Simple subtraction isn't the right approach here.

Your *actual* goal here is to shift the calendar quarters by some amount. Quarters go in a cycle from 1 to 4. Whenever you start thinking about numbers "cycling", you should be thinking of *taking the modulus*.

Quarters, by definition, are modulo 4
You shift mathematical functions left-right on a graph when you add or subtract from the "X" value

So with that in mind, we get

```
MOD(
    /* The first month of a Quarter should be an integer */
    /* 8 + 4 = 12 and 12 / 3 = 4 (and not 4.33 or 4.67) */
    FLOOR( MONTH(Date) + 4 / 3 ),
    4
)
/* The modulus gets us 0-3, but we want 1-4 */
/* So just add 1 to the result of the MOD() function */
```

You also need to use `FLOOR()` here to get the appropriate result instead of `CEILING()`, because you want October to be in Q1 (given that August is the start of your "Q1").
(10 + 4) / 3 => 4.67
4 mod 4 + 1 = 1
5 mod 4 + 1 = 2

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Derek's approach, we can also try with `CASE` function.

Since Q1 corresponds to August i.e. 8th month , we need to subtract 7 to equalise it with January which is normally the start of Q1.

Months range from 1 to 12 , we need to take absolute value of it as we are subtracting 7 from it.
We can just associate month numbers with respective quarters and use CASE function as below :

```
CASE(
    ABS(
        MONTH(
            My_date__c
        ) - 7
    ),
    1,
    1,
    2,
    1,
    3,
    1,
    4,
    2,
    5,
    2,
    6,
    2,
    7,
    3,
    8,
    3,
    9,
    3,
    10,
    4,
    11,
    4,
    12,
    4,
    0
)
```

Let's say someone needs the quarter to start from `April` , then they need to simply subtract 3 from the month like `ABS(MONTH( My_date__c )-3)`. Rest of the mappings remain same.

Case function - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_case.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **MOD** function to adjust the month number based on the FY start month. The **MOD** function returns the remainder after a number is divided by a divisor. You can use this function to calculate the fiscal quarter of a date by adding the **FY** start month minus one to the month number, and then dividing it by three and taking the ceiling.

You can use the following formula:

```
CEILING( MOD( MONTH( date ) + 7, 12 ) / 3 )
```

This formula returns the fiscal quarter of a date if the **FY** starts in Aug. For example, if the date is 2021-09-15, the formula returns 1, which is the first quarter of the FY.

You can also use the **CASE** function to assign the fiscal quarter based on the month number. The **CASE** function evaluates an expression and returns a value based on a specified condition. You can use this function to assign the fiscal quarter of a date by comparing the month number with the FY start month and the following months.

You can use the following formula:

```
CASE( MONTH( date ),
8, 1, // Aug is the first quarter
9, 1, // Sep is the first quarter
10, 1, // Oct is the first quarter
11, 2, // Nov is the second quarter
12, 2, // Dec is the second quarter
1, 2, // Jan is the second quarter
2, 3, // Feb is the third quarter
3, 3, // Mar is the third quarter
4, 3, // Apr is the third quarter
5, 4, // May is the fourth quarter
6, 4, // Jun is the fourth quarter
7, 4, // Jul is the fourth quarter
0 // Default value
)
```

This formula returns the fiscal quarter of a date if the **FY** starts in Aug. For example, if the date is 2021-09-15, the formula returns 1, which is the first quarter of the FY.